# Do we call them "a piece or section of a tangerine"?

Tags: word-request

Look at this picture
[image]

a tangerine has many small pieces in it.

Do we call them "**a piece or section of a tangerine**"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Those pieces are called **segments**.

> MATHEMATICS
>   part of a circle that is divided from the rest by a line,
>   or part of a sphere that is divided from the rest by two planes
>
> one of the small parts that a fruit such as an orange is naturally divided
>   into:
>   The salad was decorated with segments of orange.

[Segment (Cambridge Dictionary)](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/segment)